# connecting html and css files in flask web app in pycharm

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I am trying to connect html and css files in flask app (pycharm ide) but not getting as how to do this.Here is the screenshot [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YpKW.png)

Comment: add code of `flaskdata.py` in the question. Let us see what have you been trying to add the templates.

Answer (score 0):

In the template file to add CSS/JS use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
```

In `flaskdata.py` (I assume this is the main file) render the template you have added:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, request, url_for
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Thus you can continue adding static CSS/JS files in the templates and render the required template in suitable routings.